# Regular expression to inline String.format calls – replace %s with String concatenation

Tags: java, regex, refactoring

In the code base that I inherited, someone seemed to have liked `String.format` and wrote code like the following:

```
String.format("%s: %s", message, e.getMessage())
```

I would like to replace the `String.format` call by a simple string concatenation, i.e.

```
message + ": " + e.getMessage()
```

This can certainly be sped up search/replace with regular expressions, can't it?

Comment: If that `e` is an `Exception`, that code is useless anyway. Logging exceptions without stacktrace is rubbish. Also it's unclear why you want to replace it? You could be using your time a lot better.

Comment: You are right, the example is broken beyond repair. But I have other examples where replacing the `String.format` improved the readability of reasonable code. Readability is important IMHO... but let's not start a flame war on this :)

Comment: Readability is also somewhat opinion based, so if you're running regexes on the whole codebase just to make it more readable in your opinion, it's still very dubious use of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be challenging to achieve this with regular expressions. Consider the following search/replace patterns:

Search:

```regex
String\.format\(\s*"([^%]*)%s([^%]*)%s([^%]*)",\s*([^,()]*),\s*([^,()]*)\)
```

Replace:

```regex
"\1" + \4 + "\2" + \5 + "\3"
```

These patterns (and variations thereof) have several issues:

- They only work with a fixed number of `%s` strings to be replaced.
- They generate empty strings if the the format strings starts or ends with `%s`.
- They can't handle arbitrary arguments. In the form above, only variables are accepted. Arguments which include method calls like `e.getMessage()` won't work.

You could work around these problems by repeatedly adapting the expressions, but it is questionable if this is then still saving you work.

---

If you want to try it anyway, I'd recommend the following approach:

1. Find the pattern with the largest number of `%s` placeholders that you want to process and adapt the search and replace patterns to the required number of arguments.
2. In turn, adapt each of the arguments patterns so that they match your arguments. For example if you have arguments with a simple method call like `e.getMessage()`, replace the appropriate `([^,()]*)` pattern by `([^,()]*\(\))`
3. Continue with the expressions for one `%s` placeholder less.
4. Remove all concatenated empty strings by replacing `(+\s*"")|(""\s+)` by nothing.

Answer (score -2):

I would not recommend that for performance reasons.

When you use concatenation the String pool will fill up quickly because for every concatenation you do, a new copy of the String is created.

Comment: No, this is not a performance problem. The compiler optimizes the concatenation to use a StringBuilder or whatever is the fastest.

Comment: String concatenation uses `invokedynamic` since Java 9: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280